# How to set in table for all records with same name the same id number of column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to set same number 'priority' with one query for Mercedes.

```
+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
|        cars         |    place    |   priority  |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
|Aston Martin         |Moscov       |1            |
|Mercedes Benz        |Paris        |3            |
|Aston Martin         |Moscov       |1            |
|Ferrari Testarossa   |New York     |2            |
|Ferrari Testarossa   |Moscov       |2            |
|Subaru impreza       |Paris        |4            |
|Aston Martin         |Paris        |1            |
|Aston Martin         |New York     |1            |
|Mercedes Benz        |Moscov       |3            |
|Subaru impreza       |New York     |4            |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Your question is not clear...

Comment: question not clear but may be your expecting is  update table_name set priority=1 where cars='Mercedes Benz'

Comment: When a question's unclear, why not mark it as 'unclear'?

Answer (score 0):

May be something like

```
Update table_name
set priority = case when cars ='Mercedes Benz' then 1 
when cars ='Aston martin' then 2 
when cars ='Subaru Impreza' then 3 end;
```

You can update all cars priority in single query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET priority = 1
WHERE cars = 'Mercedes Benz'
```

Comment: Query may help but do explain your query.